# How to split comma separated values stored in XML node and display as individual records Without using function- SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to split a csv data inside an xml node column and display as individual records. I am using SQL server 2012. I want a query without creating a function.

The data is as follows for example

```
ID : 1  
XMLvalue : <BETA>
  <SERIAL NAME="ASSESSMENT"> ASSESSMENT=1,ASSESSMENT=2,ASSESSMENT=3</SERIAL>

<SERIAL NAME="PROJECT"> PROJECT=1,PROJECT=2,PROJECT=3</SERIAL>
</BETA>

ID : 2
XMLvalue : <BETA>
  <SERIAL NAME="ASSESSMENT"> ASSESSMENT=4,ASSESSMENT=5,ASSESSMENT=6</SERIAL>

<SERIAL NAME="PROJECT"> PROJECT=4,PROJECT=5,PROJECT=6</SERIAL>
</BETA>

ID : 3
XMLvalue : <BETA>
  <SERIAL NAME="ASSESSMENT"> ASSESSMENT=7,ASSESSMENT=8,ASSESSMENT=9</SERIAL>

<SERIAL NAME="PROJECT"> PROJECT=7,PROJECT=8,PROJECT=9</SERIAL>
</BETA>
```

The output should be as follows

```
ID     Assessment/PROJECT

1      ASSESSMENT=1    

1      ASSESSMENT=2    

1      ASSESSMENT=3    

2      ASSESSMENT=4    

2      ASSESSMENT=5    

2      ASSESSMENT=6    

3      ASSESSMENT=7    

3      ASSESSMENT=8    

3      ASSESSMENT=9    

1     PROJECT=1

1    PROJECT=2

1   PROJECT=3

2   PROJECT=4

2   PROJECT=5

2   PROJECT=6

3   PROJECT=7

3   PROJECT=8

3   PROJECT=9
```

I want to achieve the above output without creating a function and only using a query.
I was not able to create a SQL Fiddle, so following are the create and insert statement below.

```
CREATE TABLE Chart (StoreID int PRIMARY KEY,
                    XMLvalue xml);

INSERT INTO Chart
VALUES (1, '<BETA>
      <SERIAL NAME="ASSESSMENT"> ASSESSMENT=1,ASSESSMENT=2,ASSESSMENT=3</SERIAL>

    <SERIAL NAME="PROJECT"> PROJECT=1,PROJECT=2,PROJECT=3</SERIAL>
    </BETA>');

INSERT INTO Chart
VALUES (2, '<BETA>
      <SERIAL NAME="ASSESSMENT"> ASSESSMENT=4,ASSESSMENT=5,ASSESSMENT=6</SERIAL>

    <SERIAL NAME="PROJECT"> PROJECT=4,PROJECT=5,PROJECT=6</SERIAL>
    </BETA>');

INSERT INTO Chart
VALUES (3, '<BETA>
      <SERIAL NAME="ASSESSMENT"> ASSESSMENT=7,ASSESSMENT=8,ASSESSMENT=9</SERIAL>

    <SERIAL NAME="PROJECT"> PROJECT=7,PROJECT=8,PROJECT=9</SERIAL>
    </BETA>');
```

This is a continuation to my previous post.
[How to split comma separated values stored in XML node Without using function- SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567289/how-to-split-comma-separated-values-stored-in-xml-node-without-using-function-s)

Please note the output of both the requirement are different.

Comment: There are 100's of questions on Stack Overflow with answers on how to read xml data, and how to split delimited data with SQL Server, have you read and tried any of them? If not, I suggest having a read of them; you would have been presented with several candidates that likely answered your question when you were writing your question. If you have read them, what were the attempts you made? (Edit your question with your SQL attempts.) Also,  if you are using SQL Server 2012, why did you tag 2008 as well? I've removed this tag, but if it's important to your question please explain why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split comma separated values stored in XML node Without using function- SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567289/how-to-split-comma-separated-values-stored-in-xml-node-without-using-function-s)

Comment: Lol, it's not a possible duplicate, @SMor it's a literal duplicate. 

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, it is a continuation to my previous post. I was able to achieve what I had posted in my previous post. Now the requirement is a little different.I want all the records row wise.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is a little cleaner than the prior post

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  Chart A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item   = x.v.value('@NAME','VARCHAR(max)')
                      ,Value  = x.v.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(max)')
                 From  XMLvalue.nodes('/BETA/*') x(v)
             ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(B.Value,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       ASSESSMENT=1
1   2       ASSESSMENT=2
1   3       ASSESSMENT=3
2   1       ASSESSMENT=4
2   2       ASSESSMENT=5
2   3       ASSESSMENT=6
3   1       ASSESSMENT=7
3   2       ASSESSMENT=8
3   3       ASSESSMENT=9
1   1       PROJECT=1
1   2       PROJECT=2
1   3       PROJECT=3
2   1       PROJECT=4
2   2       PROJECT=5
2   3       PROJECT=6
3   1       PROJECT=7
3   2       PROJECT=8
3   3       PROJECT=9
```

> **EDIT -**

Use OUTER APPLY if you want to see NULL values.

Comment: Some people like to be sarcastic for no reason and some people just like to help people just like you.. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Patchai We all need a little assist from time-to-time.  Happy to help